# Duda sobre ventanas java

Tags: java

queria consultarles un problema que tengo estoy creando una aplicacion y en cierto jFrame cuando modifico su codigo no cambia, es decir no se notan los cambios visulmente.

Comment: ¿Puedes pegar el código que tienes y el cambio que estás tratando de hacer?

Comment: Pon tu código en la pregunta. Posiblemente necesitas usar `repaint` o `revalidate` en tus componentes.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!